# Blue prism automation

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I’m automating importing VBOs to blue prism. I’ve developed successfully up until the final screen where one has to click the “finish” button.

Even as a user clicking enter on my keyboard does not work. Please assist - perhaps there’s a shortcut I can use?

Answer (score 3):

Blue Prism has a command line interface which can be used for importing VBOs.

the command looks like this:

```
AutomateC.exe /user admin password /import "VBO\BPA Object - Calendars.xml"
```

Comment: You should go for this approach instead of making a robot to do it, you could also find more detail of how to do this, in the document "v6 User Guide - Installing Enterprise Edition" hosted in the blue prism portal

https://portal.blueprism.com/system/files/documents/v6%20User%20Guide%20-%20Installing%20Enterprise%20Edition_1_1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Use Root Element and start sending "Global Send Key" for enter keystroke "{ENTER}" use this one and definitely it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to Map it as a Region, or as a Win32 element if the HTML is not working.
Last change, inject javascript code to trigger the download but it's a bit harder.

Comment: javascript insertion is not recommended though. It's being removed. What is likely happening is an "onchange" event is not being triggered. In order to make that happen you can do 2 things. 1. Use sendkeys to "Tab" over to the button... OR use a "focus" action to make the button active. THEN use an Enter or Space bar keystroke to activate the button. 2. The only other way to do it (If you don't inject javascript from BP which is not recommended) is to use sendkeys to open the browser console (Control + Shift + J). Send your Javascript into this console. Then spy the "X" to close it.